# Genymotion OpenGL in a Virtual OS

Tags: android, opengl-es, virtualbox, genymotion

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop, and inside Ubuntu I hava installed Windows 7 as a virtual OS, using Oracle VirtualBox. I also have Genymotion (together with Oracle VirtualBox) inside my virtual Windows 7, and have downloaded Galaxy S5 as a virtual device in Genymotion. Now while starting my virtual Galaxy device, the following message appears.

[image]

I've downloaded and installed the appropriate driver for my laptop's graphics card in virtual Windows 7, but that doesn't seem to be working properly in my virtual Windows 7. What can I do to solve this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nested virtualisation is not supported in Genymotion. A solution should be to install it directly on Ubuntu.

If you explain a little bit more what you want to achieve with this setup I can try to help you more.